# UIAlertController behaves differently after TestFlight Beta Installation

Tags: ios, swift, testflight, uialertcontroller

Newbie here needed some help.

1. I'm using Parse BaaS to facilitate a simple messaging app.
2. I've have successfully submitted my app to iTunes Connect.
3. I have switched ON TestFlight Beta Testing.
4. I have added 2 Internal Testers.
5. I have successfully installed on two different devices.

For the app: 
I have two tableView one in mainViewController and one in directMessageViewController.

The mainViewController has

1. a TableViewContoller to display a list of messages and
2. a UIAlertController to enter username and password to login.

The directMessageViewContoller has

1. Another TableViewContoller to display a list of users to choose from
2. A UIAlertController to enter the message text

Here is the problem:
When I run this app directly in Xcode with my iPhone connected. Everything works perfectly fine. I can login, select other users and send a direct push notification message.

However, when I submit the exact same app to iTunes Connect with TestFlight Beta, the directMessageViewController text field becomes a password field. Even the placeholder text become "Your password..." And the receiving of push notification doesn't work anymore.

Here is the code

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    var messageAlert:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "New Direct Message", message: "Enter your message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    messageAlert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler{

        (directMessageField: UITextField!) -> Void in

        directMessageField.placeholder = "Your message..."
    }

    messageAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Send", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:
        {
            (alertAction:UIAlertAction!)-> Void in

            var pushQuery:PFQuery = PFInstallation.query()
            pushQuery.whereKey("user", equalTo: self.userList.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row))

            var push:PFPush = PFPush()
            push.setQuery(pushQuery)

            let textfields:NSArray = messageAlert.textFields as AnyObject! as NSArray
            let messageTextField:UITextField = textfields.objectAtIndex(0) as UITextField

            push.setMessage(messageTextField.text)
            push.sendPushInBackgroundWithTarget(nil, selector: nil)


    }))

    messageAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(messageAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Did I do anything wrong in the UIAlertController? Thanks in advance.